# merging layers of raster data of the same format

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layers, merge

My map consists of several different grid-layers lying right next to each other.

I want to merge them to one single layer so that i can analyse my whole map at once.

How can i do that?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm working with ArcGIS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is called [Mosaic to new raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000098000000). It sits in the Data management toolbox under Raster/Raster Dataset.

If your rasters are all neatly aligned, you don't have to worry about the mosaic operator. However if any of the rasters overlap, the mosaic operator gives you the ability to choose which value or which raster should get preference.